# Windows Server installation media download

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation installed on it. I have label (WinSvr 2008 R2 Foundation ROK 1CPU) with product key on it.

Is it possible to perform clean installation and where can I find (download) installation media?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the media from Microsoft. http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/default.aspx. You can also contact MS and give them your key and they can send you a link to download.